# Usage of Connected App in terms of exposing a RestResource API for consumption?

Tags: apex, apexrest, connected-apps, restresource

I know I have done it before, but I am lost this time around. Previously, I have created Connected Apps for implementation of Oauth 2.0 authentication process with Salesforce. But, this environment is different. We already have a connected app, an Integration profile set up in Salesforce. I have created a RestResource Apex Class, and am not sure as to which details to be shared with the Vendor now, who will be consuming this API for their use.

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to:

- Provide the consumer key/secret from the connected app
- Ensure that the vendor is setup as a user in your environment
- The vendor then utilizes [one of the flows to authenticate](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm) themselves, get the access token and then invoke the api.